# cypress should be called with value test

Tags: cypress

Looking for a test like below. Basically I get it to work using   `cy.get('@myLog').should('be.called')` but I'm trying to test the value console log is using when called. In jest it would be toHaveBeenCalledWith() so the equivalent in cypress is what I'm after ?

```
   cy.window().then((win) => {
      cy.wrap(cy.spy(win.console, 'log')).as('myLog')
    })
 
    cy.get('@myLog')
      .should('be.called')
      .and('have.value', 'clicked')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cy.spy() and cy.stub() you can use [Sinon-chai](https://github.com/domenic/sinon-chai) assertions. So for you instance you may want to use `be.calledWith`.

```js
cy.window().then((win) => {
  cy.wrap(cy.spy(win.console, 'log')).as('myLog')
})
 
cy.get('@myLog')
  .should('be.calledWith', 'clicked')
```

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I was after!